# Excel/VBA find string and copy offset cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in need of a small piece of VBA to do the following, 
search for a particular string, for instance ("New Applications"), and then copy the cells offset (0,2) and (0,5). Hence if "New Applications" is found in A34, I then need to copy D34 and J34…

Any help, much appreciated.

All I have so far is as below, but i'm sure how to also copy offset(0,5)..

```
Sub test()
Cells.Find(What:="NB ASDA Applications", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    Selection.Copy
```

The rest of the code, re pasting etc I already have, I just need to amend a small part to something like above.

many thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are somewhat familiar with the terminology. Please share your code and explain where you got stuck. Mention whether the string will be the entire cell contents or partial. Can there be more than one match? Where do you paste what you have copied? Or what else do you do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it would greatly help to use a variable.

```
Sub test()
    'make a variable called foundrange that is of type "Range"
    Dim foundRange as Range

    'set this variable based on what is found: (note we remove the 'activate' here
    Set foundRange = Cells.Find(What:="NB ASDA Applications", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'You can copy now and do whatever you want. Say you want to copy these values to Sheet2!A1 and B1, respectively:
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Value = foundRange.OFfset(0,2).value
    Sheet2.Range("B1").Value = foundRange.Offset(0,5).value 

    'Or copy to the clipboard -- haven't tested this union, but I think it should work
    Union(foundRange.Offset(0,2), foundRange.Offset(0,5)).Copy  

    'Or copy just one and do something
    foundRange.Offset(0,2).Copy
    'do something

    'Copy the other one and do something
    foundRange.Offset(0,5).Copy
    'do something
```